# How to query the third property given any other two properties?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have three properties that can take different values

```
from to delta

a b 1
a c 2
b a 1
```

I want a function when given values of any two properties, gives the value of other third property.

for example given `from` and `to` gives `delta`, or given `to` and `delta` gives `from`.

What is an efficient data structure to utilize this type of query?

Comment: How long is your list? If it's only 3 items, just search it top to bottom until a match is found. Even for 1000 items this is still plenty fast for most use cases.

Comment: I'd probably create an object using the known elements as the keys and the unknown as the value.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Strings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation.  It assumes that you want to call with known specific properties (`from`, `to`, `delta`) and not for instance an arbitrary `'a'` and `1`, which could map either the first or third record.

We pass an object with the known keys and get back the first record that matches those keys.  Note that it gives you back the entire lookup object, not a specific field.  While that could be changed, I think this is more flexible.

If no matching record is found, it will return `undefined`.

```js
const findMatch = (lookups) => (value) =>
  lookups.find (lookup => Object .keys (lookup). every (
    key => !(key in value) || lookup [key] == value [key]
  ))

const lookup = findMatch (
  [
    {from: 'a', to: 'b', delta: 1},
    {from: 'a', to: 'c', delta: 2},
    {from: 'b', to: 'a', delta: 1},
  ]
)

console .log (lookup ({from: 'a', delta: 1}))
console .log (lookup ({from: 'a', to: 'c'}))
console .log (lookup ({to: 'a', delta: 1 }))
console .log (lookup ({from: 'b', to: 'c'})) //=> undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If you wanted to get the specific value back, we could rewrite like this:

```
const findMatch = (lookups) => (target, value) =>
  (lookups.find (lookup => Object .keys (lookup). every (
    key => !(key in value) || lookup [key] == value [key]
  )) || {}) [target]

const lookup = findMatch ( /* ... */)
```

and call it like this:

```
console .log (lookup ('to', {from: 'a', delta: 1}))    //=> b
console .log (lookup ('delta', {from: 'a', to: 'c'}))  //=> 2
```